# How to decrypt data from Entity Framework using C#, which is encrypted using symmetric key and certificate in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, encryption, encryption-symmetric

In SQL Server:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY TestEncryption DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MyCertificate

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), DECRYPTBYKEY(EncryptColumn)) 
FROM Table1
```

How to get the decrypted value equivalent of this SQL query code in C# using Entity Framework? Is it even possible?

Comment: The Select is a query and returns results.  So create a SQLCommand with the query text as the string and the execute then command.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Yes, I am aware of data can be retrieve using ADO.net. My question is if it is possible to get result using entity framework or any C# algorithm to decrypt it?

Comment: Encryption algorithms are an industry standard so data encrypted on one system can be decrypted on different systems.  So as long as you have the algorithm and key you should be able to fully decrypt in c#.  The certificate is ASCII and should give you the algorithm.